# TikZposter: display half transparent picture in background of block?

Tags: tikz-pgf, backgrounds

I am trying to make a poster with TikZposter and would like to place a half transparent picture in the background of i.e. the following block:

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetheme{Default}
\begin{document}
\block{My Block}{
 Some text\\
 \begin{align*}
   M+A=T+H
 \end{align*}
}
\end{document}
```

so that text and equations are written over the picture in the background. It would also be nice to be able to adjust the position of the picture in the background. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `tikzpicture` isn't actually `tikzpicture` (page 7 tikzposter manual), but it seems to do the trick.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newsavebox{\textbox}
\usetheme{Default}
\begin{document}
\block[bodyinnersep=0pt]{My Block}{%
\savebox{\textbox}{\parbox{\linewidth}{%
   Some text\\
 \begin{align*}
   M+A=T+H
 \end{align*}
}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \node[inner sep=0pt,opacity=.5]{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height={\dimexpr\ht\textbox+\dp\textbox}]{example-image}};
  \node[inner sep=0pt]{\usebox{\textbox}};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]